# Cakephp input controller's function id through URL

Tags: php, cakephp

In Cake,

How would you put id through a function in control through URL?

example:
Users controller

```
function Admin($id){
blah blah
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would pass it in the URL access that page.  For example, `www.example.com/users/admin/1`.  The `1` would be passed into the `$id` field of your function.  If you were setting a link up in your view and using Cake's HTML helper it would look like:

```
$this->Html->link('your link text', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'admin', '1');
```